# Put several values into 1 cell (e.g. array{1} = [1,2,3]) for multiple condition SPM analysis; All I get is array{1} = [1] [2] [3]

Tags: matlab, analysis

I'm working to get a 1st level analysis completed on some fMRI data, and as it's my first time using SPM in this way, it seems as though there is no end to my frustrations. SPM includes these specific instructions:

"This *.mat file must include the following cell arrays (each 1 x n): names, onsets, and durations. eg. names=cell(1,5), onsets=cell(1,5), durations=cell(1,5), then names{2}="Second condition", **onsets{2}=[3,5,19,22]**,durations{2}=[0,0,0,0], contain the required details of the second condition."

The code I'm using grabs the data I need from the various excel files the behavioral data is stored in, and adds them to these cell arrays.

```
sessionFiles = dir('*.xlsx');
allNames = {sessionFiles.name}';
conditions = 36;
% go through excel files to grab relevant column information for SPM
for i=1:length(sessionFiles)
    [~,fileName,~] = fileparts(allNames{i});
    % initialize cells SPM needs
    names = cell(1,conditions);
    onsets = cell(1,conditions);
    durations = {1.75};
    durations = repmat(durations,1,conditions);    
    % read in excel file
    [num,~,~] = xlsread(sessionFiles(i).name);
    trialType = num(:,6);
    % grab condition information from columns: seconds=9, name=6
    for j=1:conditions
        index = find(trialType==j);
        trialOnsets = cell(1,length(index));
        names{1,j} = j;
        for k=1:length(index)
            trialOnsets{1,k}=double(num(index(k),9));
        end
        onsets{1,j} = trialOnsets;
    end
    % save new data for SPM
    save(fileName,'names','onsets','durations');
    clear names onsets durations fileName num raw text
end
```

I found an example which shows each cell should look like this:

[image: example format]

I just can't figure out how to grab the numbers automatically and put them in cells like that.

I know this isn't the SPM forums, but I've seen a few questions posted and I thought I would try my luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line `trialOnsets = cell(1,length(index));`, `trialOnsets` is specified as a cell array of size `1xlength(index)`. Then, `trialOnsets` is assigned to `onsets{1,j}`. With this workflow, each cell of `onsets` will be of size `1xlength(index)`.

Instead, each cell of `onsets` should be of size `1x1` and each 1x1 cell in `onsets` should have a matrix of size `1xlength(index)`. To do this, do the following.

1. Specify `trialOnsets` as a matrix, instead of as a cell array. To do this, replace `trialOnsets = cell(1,length(index));` with `trialOnsets = zeros(1,length(index));`.
2. Assign the values from `num` to `trialOnsets`, which is now a matrix (previously was a cell array). To do this, replace `trialOnsets{1,k}=double(num(index(k),9));` with `trialOnsets(1,k)=double(num(index(k),9));`.

The edited code should be as follows:

```
sessionFiles = dir('*.xlsx');
allNames = {sessionFiles.name}';
conditions = 36;
% go through excel files to grab relevant column information for SPM
for i=1:length(sessionFiles)
    [~,fileName,~] = fileparts(allNames{i});
    % initialize cells SPM needs
    names = cell(1,conditions);
    onsets = cell(1,conditions);
    durations = {1.75};
    durations = repmat(durations,1,conditions);    
    % read in excel file
    [num,~,~] = xlsread(sessionFiles(i).name);
    trialType = num(:,6);
    % grab condition information from columns: seconds=9, name=6
    for j=1:conditions
        index = find(trialType==j);
        trialOnsets = zeros(1,length(index));
        names{1,j} = j;
        for k=1:length(index)
            trialOnsets(1,k)=double(num(index(k),9));
        end
        onsets{1,j} = trialOnsets;
    end
    % save new data for SPM
    save(fileName,'names','onsets','durations');
    clear names onsets durations fileName num raw text
end
```

I could not test this code, since there was no sample data. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No problem :) Just remember to accept my answer as the best answer!